# What does -là at the end of the words mean?

Tags: grammaire, sens, pronoms, démonstratifs

For example:

> Cette année-là
>
> Ce type-là

What does *-là*  at the end of the words mean?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The suffixes [ci](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/ci) (see point III) and [là](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/l%C3%A0) (II) are used to reenforce the demonstrative adjective (*ce*, *cette*).

Their meaning is similar to the one of *this* (-ci) and *that* (-là) in English. Note that it's optional, so that *ce chat* is perfectly valid. Usually it implies *this cat* rather than *that cat*, which is why you'll less often see the *-ci* ending than the *-là* one, unless there's a need to differentiate.

If there is no noun following *this* or *that*, you'll just translate with *ceci* or *cela* (often shortened to *ça*). *This one* or *that one* translate to *celui-ci* or *celui-là*.

Comment: In the case of `cette année` I wouldn't say it's optional, because without it, you would be referring to the current year rather than to some year past.

Comment: "Usually it implies this cat rather than that cat, which is why you'll less often see the -ci ending than the -là one," But if it implies "this cat" should i more often see the -ci ending?? You mentioned   this (-ci) ...

Comment: @Phong well if you say _cette année-ci_ without any other form of context, it would also mean the current year, not any one in the past. But I agree that sometimes the meaning differs with or without suffix. Note that by "optional", I meant "grammatically" optional :-)

Comment: @DrStrangeLove maybe I wasn't too clear on that point. Bascially people will say _ce chat-là_ for _that cat_, but for _this cat_ they'll more often say _ce chat_. So you see more often _-là_ than _-ci_ because _-ci_ is often omitted. And I'm not sure I'm more clear, but there you go.

Answer (score 3):

That one.

- *Cette année-là je vivais à Paris.* → That year I was living in Paris.
- *Ce type-là est asocial.* → That guy is unsociable.

Answer (score 2):

*-là* **et pas un(e) autre**,

- ni l'année en cours
- ni un autre type présent,

pour compléter les exemples donnés.